# Does anyone know if there is a way to use JBoss (4.2.3) as an SMTP server?

Tags: email, jboss, smtp

I'm after a way of not having to poll an inbox to receive messages, but to receive them directly in JBoss instead. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any lightweight way of doing this. There is a java SMTP server ([James](http://james.apache.org/)), but it's a beast of an application.

You may be able to write it by hand, though, if all you need to do is listen on port 25 and make the appropriate SMTP noises. That means reading up on the SMTP spec to see how to implement enough of the protocol to accept incoming deliveries. You then have the problem of getting JBoss to listen on port 25, which is a root-protected port on unix.

Overall, it's probably far less effort to maintain a separate SMTP server external to JBoss, and poll it over POP3/IMAP.